# I am new in R. I wanted to subset only 500 rows values but it gives me more than that values

Tags: r

I wrote this command:

```
newdata <- subset(cwur_Data, world_rank < 500, 
                  select = c(country, institution, quality_of_education))
```

Instead of creating 500 rows, it's creating more. It's creating 1198 observations.

[image]

Comment: Try `subset(cwur_Data, world_rank < 500 ,select=c(country,institution,quality_of_education))[1:500,]` if you want only first 500 rows from that subset.

Answer (score 0):

It tends to be much easier to use brackets for the same purpose. I believe that the result you want could be achieved by doing the following:

```
cwur_Data[cwur_Data$world_rank <= 500, ]
```

Using this technique, the value before the comma represents which rows we want to select, in this case rows whose world_rank is less than or equal to 500. The value after the comma represents the columns we want to select. In this case we leave it blank because we want all of the columns.